# How PHP template engine refesh data?

Tags: php, templates, smarty3

I'm new to PHP template (Smarty), and I have a question about it:
PHP template translate PHP and html script to cache, such as:

```
*0c11aeb3a17645e71660028291bd3148b19cef94.file.group_add.tpl.php*
```

and when web contents (may be which relies on database) changed, the cache may be refreshed and updated, this will cause/consume IO overhead because it needs to generate new cache.

I think this may be slow, and How the template engine solve this? or how to design sites to avoid this occasion?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe look on the smarty page for details. My first guess would be the modified date of the tpl file. As long as the tpl file isnt changed smarty won't recompile  it. I'm sure of that

Answer (score 1):

Smarty handle cache in the background, cache file is a precompiled php file, the file is a static templates with scripts or definition for dynamic contents. Though content is dynamic, the script is the same.

The overhead only in first compilation, subsequently it just read off and use the template, usually very fast. Slowness could be due to db or other task.

Cache file updates or refresh or recompilation is managed by smarty, usually triggered when:

1. original template file is changed (from the modified time);
2. defined cache life time (default 3600 secs or 1 hour) expired.

This setting can be overridden. For smarty cache setting read at http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/caching